# How to only set `selected` against an `option` instead of `selected="selected"`

Tags: jquery, dropdown, selected

I want to change

```
<option value="2">Samsung</option>
```

to

```
<option selected value="2">Samsung</option>
```

by jquery.

jquery `attr` and `prop` prints the whole `selected="selected"`.

Comment: is there an issue when you set selected="selected"?

Comment: This looks like an XY problem - why do you think you need just `selected` and not some other way to select that option?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `.replaceWith` to replace with explicit HTML:

```js
$("select option[value=2]")
    .replaceWith("<option selected value='2'>2</option>")
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
 <option value="1">1</option>
 <option value="2">2</option>
 <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

But it's not clear what problem this is meant to solve vs setting by value `.val(2)`

```js
$("select").val("2")
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks...  In materialize drop down it works when selected is there in markup